# Need help in modelling ER diagram

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have 3 drop downs : Category, Subcategory and Action

Each Category may or may not have a subcategories

Case 1 : Category having subcategories

The Action drop down is mapped to each of the subcategories

Case 2 : Category NOT having subcategories

The Action drop down is directly mapped to the Category drop down

How to represent these 3 entities , namely Category,Subcategory and Action in an ER diagram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic Bill of Materials example.  The simplest way is with one CategoryAction table.

```
CategoryAction
--------------
CategoryAction ID (PK)
Category / Action Flag
CategoryAction Name
CategoryAction Description
Parent CategoryAction ID (FK)
```

The category has a null parent category action ID.  The subcategory points back to a parent category.  The action points back to either a parent subcategory or a parent category.

The advantage of this structure is you have unlimited levels of subcategories.

You query this table in stages.  First, you get all the category rows (the rows with a null parent category action ID).  Next, you query all the subcategories and actions for a category.  Finally, you query all the actions for a subcategory.